# javascript object copy and modifying dynamic data

Tags: javascript, object

here is an object

```
let a = {
 b: 1
}
```

lets add some properties invoking the objects property

```
a.c = a.b
// a:{ b:1, c:1}
```

now i would like to copy the object in an other file and modify the b property which should( at least in my head) modify the c property too, as it depended on a.b

```
// in an other file
const a = require('a');
let copiedObject = Object.assign({}, a);
copiedObject.b = 2;
console.log(copiedObject.c) // outputs 1
```

my question is: how can i achive that the last console log returns 2 as ive overwritten the object's b value and the c value should depend on b?

Comment: _"as it depended on a.b"_ - No, it doesn't. You've just copied the value that is/was stored in `a.b` and assigned the copy to `a.c`

Comment: okay, i understand, but how could i achive that it would work as like described?

Comment: "*i would like to copy the object in an other file*" can you explain more about this and overall what you're trying to achieve? You can use getter to dynamically determine the value of `c` based on `b` but that won't necessarily persist over a copy. Depends on how you do the copy.

Answer (score 1):

Such an assignment does not result in creating an *alias* `a.c` for `a.b`.

To achieve what you want, define `c` with a setter/getter. Now, using a getter/setter works with `a` itself, but if you use `Object.assign({}, a)`, that copy will not have the getter/setter, but just a `c` property with a value that is no longer related to the `b` property.

To avoid that, let `a` be the prototype of `copiedObject`, and then it works:

```js
let a = {
   b: 1,
   get c() { return this.b },
   set c(value) { this.b = value; }
}

a.c = 2;
console.log(a.b === a.c); // true
a.b = 3;
console.log(a.b === a.c); // true

let copiedObject = Object.create(a); // don't use Object.assign here
// Assign different values to demonstrate, that the getter/setter is "inherited"
copiedObject.b = 4;
a.b = 1;
console.log(a.b, a.c, copiedObject.b, copiedObject.c); // 1 1 4 4
// ... and via c:
copiedObject.c = 5;
a.c = 0;
console.log(a.b, a.c, copiedObject.b, copiedObject.c); // 0 0 5 5
```

Just be aware that with this setup, reading `copiedObject.b` will return the value of `a.b` for as long as no assignment is made to `copiedObject.b`, because there is not (yet) an owned property `b` on `copiedObject`. Once you assign to `copiedObject.b`, that property is now an own property, with its distinctive value, separate from `a.b`.

If you want this separation to happen immediately, then do `Object.assign(copiedObject, copiedObject)` as soon as the object is created.

Comment: From [MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create): "The Object.create() method creates a new object, using an existing object as the prototype of the newly created object." This is a great answer, but just wanted to mention that there are a few caveats/implications of prototyping: changes made to getters/setters in original object *after* the `create` will continue to affect the copied object. Also getters/setters in original object will be part of its `getOwnPropertyNames`, but not in copied object.

Comment: @David784, indeed, using prototypal inheritance has its characteristics to be aware of. Good point!

Answer (score 0):

To actively update a value, you need a function.

You can use:
 - a method that **updates a separate, stored value (solution 1)**, or
 - one that **always returns the current value (solution 2)**.

(Note: JavaScript [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) are intended to do this job, as indicated in another answer, but they use a bit of "magic", so if you're new to object methods, you might want to start with something simpler like one of these two solutions.)

**Solution 1**
`.c` is a property that must be set explicitly by invoking the `.setC` method

```js
let a = { b: 1 }
a.setC = function(){ this.c = this.b; }
//console.log(a); 

//const a = require('a');
let copiedObject = Object.assign({}, a);
copiedObject.b = 2;
copiedObject.setC();

console.log( copiedObject.c ); // 2
```

**Solution 2**
`.c` is a method (so must be used like ".c()") that returns the value of `.b`

```js
let a = { b: 1 }
a.c = function() { return this.b; }
//console.log(a); 

//const a = require('a');
let copiedObject = Object.assign({}, a);
copiedObject.b = 2;

console.log( copiedObject.c() ); // 2
```